# How to store methods in a method that take methods as a parameters with action but using Task(Async)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, task

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class Task22 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public event Action callback;
        private Task allDone;
        List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();

        async void Start()
        {
            Task a = Task.Run(Looping1);
            Task b = Task.Run(Looping2);
            Task c = Task.Run(Looping3);
            TaskDone(a,b,c);
        }
    
        async Task TaskDone(params Task\[\] tasks)
        {
            foreach (Task task in tasks)
            {
                allTasks.Add(task);
            }

            Task allTaskDone = Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
            await allTaskDone;

            Debug.Log("AllTaskDone");
        }

        async Task Looping1()
        {
            Debug.Log("StartTask1");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Debug.Log("Task1Done");
        }

        async Task Looping2()
        {
            Debug.Log("StartTask2");
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Debug.Log("Task2Done");
        }

        async Task Looping3()
        {
            Debug.Log("StartTask3");
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            Debug.Log("Task3Done");
        }
    }
```

[image]

This is my output, although I don't understand why the output start with task 1 then 3 then 2. Since I add them with tasks a,b, and c, following the order of Task1 Task2, Task3 and code should run line by line. But that's just an additional question.

My main question is currently I can add the task into the "TaskDone" method, but all those tasks I need to declare first at the start and I want to skip this part. What I want to achieve is to create is to able to throw any task or method directly to a method that takes action as a parameter. The method doesn't know the number of tasks is thrown in but still able to handle it all.

Sorry if I am a bit unclear as I am a beginner and didn't find the answer I want on the internet

```
 async Task TaskDoneAction(Action tasks//To store the task or throw method directly to here)
    {
        // Then I just do a for loop to see how many method or task is thrown here and add them to the list and do a callback when all tasks is done

        Task allTaskDone = Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
        await allTaskDone;
        Debug.Log("AllTaskDone");
    }
```

Comment: You'd better edit your question to add the actual problem you have, your current question is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You are mixing async (i.e. async/await) with concurrency (i.e. Task.Run). You should probably stick to one or the other. Avoid using both at the same time, at least in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the order of starting tasks (that are meant to be started on the same time) are practically random (depends on so many thing and current state of the thread pool and task scheduler so it can be considered random), and you should not rely on it.
2. The method can have parameters of type Func. However you have to still start the task somewhere, but it can be done in the method itself, like:

```
    async Task RunAll(params Func<Task>[] methods)
    {
        var tasks = methods.Select(m=>Task.Run(m)).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    
    async Task Main()
    {
        await RunAll(Looping1, Looping2, Looping3);
    }
```

Comment: I have another question, why can't I use action, but use Func instead? I thought Func is only used when there's something that needs to be returned. And action is for void. However, isn't Task just the same as void when I didn't  add any return type to the Task? Thank you

Comment: @aronkan no .. `Task` returns `Task` and `void` returns nothing ;)

Comment: oh, no wonder thanks. Because when I have the Task method, inside the body I didn't need to type return Task that's why I thought it didn't return anything. Thanks!

Comment: Why `m => Task.Run(m)` and not `m => m()`?

Comment: to run them all in parallel in case that there is a cpu-intensive or time consuming work inside (usually before first await, however the awaited tasks can be completed or run synchronously)